# Why am i getting error: 'ts' object must have one or more observations when I run command ggsdc from ggseas package?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a customized seasonal decomposed plot. I found the package `ggseas` that should be able to give me the kind of plot I'm looking for using the `ggsdc` command. This is the code I ran:

```
 jd_df %>% ggsdc(jd_df, aes(x = Week.of.reporting, y = n), frequency = 53, start = 2009, method = "stl", s.window = "periodic") +
facet.titles = c("observed","trend", "seasonal", "irregular")) +
geom_line()
```

I keep getting this error: `Error in ts(data[, yvar], frequency = frequency) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations`

I'm not sure if there is something wrong with the format of my dataset. Any ideas?

subset of data:

```
    structure(list(year = c(2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010), Week.of.reporting = c(20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 
43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), n = c(124, 
106, 98, 158, 150, 149, 130, 94, 82, 64, 48, 48, 48, 50, 34, 
27, 27, 21, 13, 32, 39, 43, 34, 25, 30, 41, 41, 16, 10, 28, 23, 
37, 28, 27, 45, 32, 38, 46, 58, 29, 53, 69, 77, 55, 107, 112, 
107, 112, 160, 189, 159, 176, 192)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -53L))
```

Comment: That's odd. I get this error: `Error in ggsdc(jd_df, aes(x = Week.of.reporting, y = n, colour = city),  : 
  object 'jd_df' not found`

Comment: well that's my dataset, I didn't upload it here just because its sensitive

Comment: You don't have to upload it. Just a small part, with structure, so that it provides a __minimal working example__ for the folks here who are more than willing to try to help you.

Comment: I've added a link to the dataset in the post.

Comment: how about dput(head(my_data, n = 40)) rather than the link. But in any case, the `ts` error is saying it is not finding observations, as in any.

Comment: @Chris yes exactly, that doesnt make any sense to me. I'm able to create a plot using the commands `ts` and `stl` but i was hoping for something a bit more sophisticated so I could create an aesthetically pleasing plot.

Comment: I'm starting by simplifying, i.e. dropping the magritter and just doing `ggsdc(jd_df`, which may be the problem anyway because you actually don't need the `jd_df` after the `%>%` because the call is like `jd_df %>% ggsdc( . , ` and doesn't need to be named at all, becoming `jd_df %>% ggsdc(aes(`, i think. But you also have one too many `)` in facet.titles. The # of rows isn't sufficient to use frequency = 53, so I currently get different errors.

Comment: Ok. So I've changed the subset in the original post so you get 53 rows of data. I tried the code without: `+
facet.titles = c("observed","trend", "seasonal", "irregular")) +
geom_line()` but i still get the same error.